# Android: How to keep both signed and debug version of my app in the same phone?

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed and app and it is currently in play store. But as I keep on making changes for bug fixes, I want to keep both the play store version(signed) and debug version in my phone **without changing package name** repeatedly. For now, while developing, I keep one package name and just before release I change the package name of the app. This does not seem to be the right practice though. Can anyone help me understanding the right approach so that I dont have to change the package name and can keep both signed and debug version of app in my phone ?

Answer (score 3):

you need to have different packagenames - but there is an easy way to do so:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
     debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
     }
    }
}
```